# Why can't I have unique sorting options for folders in Finder?

Tags: finder, macos, sort

For example, when I set the Documents folder in my user folder to "Sort by: Kind", it also sets the sorting option for every other folder on my computer. Can I have unique folder sorting options? Or is it impossible?

EDIT: This is on El Capitan.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, unique sort order is possible.

1. Open a new Finder window for e.g. Documents and
2. Go to View > Show View Options or hit Command + J.
3. Define your Sort order. That's it. Close the window
4. Repeat the step for every window. This way you can define the Sort order for every Finder window.

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work on my iMac. It just sets the same sorting options for every single folder on my computer.

Comment: @lempamo do not hit the button "use as defaults". This will define the sort order to all folders. Simply close the view options window

Comment: There is no button labeled "Use As Defaults" on my version of OS X.

Comment: I have updated my previous answer. Be sure to open a new Finder window for every folder in order to define a unique sorting order.

Answer (score 0):

You said: “There is no button labeled "Use As Defaults" on my version of OS X."
But there is, or should be.
Opene diskUtility, select your disk and hit the FirstAid tab: it will correct the permissions; then restart the mac. This will probably help.